# Run parity in warp up to a certain block and archive mode after that

Tags: parity, warp-sync

Is there a way I can run parity in warp up to a certain non-latest block, say starting from block 3,000,000 after the network spam and full archival mode after that?

Comment: That's an excellent question because the blocks related to the DDOS are a huge source of the slow synchronizing. I can't wait to hear the answer for this.

Comment: The answer is no. And the DDoS blocks are not the only problem. The whole ICO-mania comes close to a similar throughput for blocks after 3_000_000.